# Wordpress shows wp_editor codes in rendered source code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

You can find full rendered code below jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/yusufcivir/45dckxLj

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-media-frame">
    <div class="media-frame-menu"></div>
    <div class="media-frame-title"></div>
    <div class="media-frame-router"></div>
    <div class="media-frame-content"></div>
    <div class="media-frame-toolbar"></div>
    <div class="media-frame-uploader"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-media-modal">
    <div tabindex="0" class="media-modal wp-core-ui">
        <button type="button" class="media-modal-close"><span class="media-modal-icon"><span class="screen-reader-text">Ortam panelini kapat</span></span></button>
        <div class="media-modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-modal-backdrop"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-uploader-window">
    <div class="uploader-window-content">
        <h1>Yüklemek için dosyaları sürükleyip bırakın</h1>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-uploader-editor">
    <div class="uploader-editor-content">
        <div class="uploader-editor-title">Yüklemek için dosyaları sürükleyip bırakın</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I cant remove it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code originates from the "/wp-includes/media-template.php" file starting at around Line 187.

If you are seeing it in the source code of your rendered page, then there is a plugin that is including this file like this `wp_enqueue_media();`

Options to resolve:

1. Deactivate the plugin at fault - it was written with lousy code anyway
2. Edit the plugin at fault so that it does not call the above mentioned media file